# Water from fireplace

Tags: basement

One several occasions, a small small amount of water collects in the basement.  Looks like it is coming from the wall/section of foundation directly below the fireplace.  I've check the grading and downspout outside Andy eye all look good.  Was asking some friends and one thing that maybe in heavy heavy rain, the water is entering the top of the fireplace and making its way down into the basement.

Can this happen?

Comment: Why not? Does your flue have a rain cap?

Comment: Excellent question.  I will have to venture up there and look

Answer (score 1):

Rain can run down the inside of the chimney, in my last house with 2 fireplaces 1 on each floor the stack was quite large and I ended up adding a rain shield 18" above the opening to reduce the amount of water coming in. Also if the flashing on the outside of the stack has not been maintained water can run down the outside.